# Is there a way using python or an image analysis software to compare two lines?

Tags: python, imagej, fiji

I am trying to find a method of comparing/quantifying zebrafish spines through either a python script or image analysis software. If I can trace the spines and collect a set of "experimental" lines, does anyone know of a way to compare each of these lines to a "standardized" line? If possible, I would like to get the positive and negative areas between each of the experimental lines and standardized line. In addition, is there a way to get a number for how many times the tangent vector to the experimental lines changes its vertical direction (ie, the amount of local minima/maxima in a line or the amount)? I have played around with Fiji but can't find anything useful/intuitive. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it's not a programming question. I'd suggest to instead ask on https://forum.image.sc where you're more likely to get help from image processing experts.

Comment: Hey Jan, I was asking if there is a way through programming. I only tried with image analysis software but someone suggested I could achieve this with just a python script. Thanks for the link, I'll try there!